# Relay access denied on sending email

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, smtp

I want to send email via my desktop app 
Here is my code

```
        MailMessage m = new MailMessage("mahmoud@isysway.com", "gavoh3d@yahoo.com", "subject", "body");
        m.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("out.tedata.net.eg");
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mahmoud@isysway.com", "password");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Send(m);
```

My problem is: this code throw an exception

```
Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1 <gavoh3d@yahoo.com>: Relay access denied
```

I think because my internet provider need outgoing server (SMTP) authentication
I config it in Outlook as below
[image]
 
Now, How can I config it in my code

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be various issues:

1. are you able to send mail to Yahoo mail from your outlook? [check this link](http://www.penpublishing.com/support/emailerrors/understandingemailerrors/default.aspx#554) If yes
2. Check [IIS SMTP Virtual Server Relay Restrictions](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/58f05ef9-55a3-42b3-9f57-27fdc8723b8a.mspx?mfr=true)

Hope this help you.

Comment: 1) I am able to send to  yahoo mail from my outlook. 2) this is a desktop app not web app, so I don't need to config IIS

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because I have the same problem. I solved it using the myNetworks entry in /etc/postfix/main.cf
Add the IP from which your sending to the myNetworks line, I think PostFix expects a space to separate IP adresses, for my eyes it's better to use a comma, but if I use both it works.

This solution is not ideal, so I'll be gratefull for a better one!

Rob